# RAILS 3 model validation inclusion in does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, inclusion

```
# ==Schema Information
# Schema version:
# Table name: terms
#  id                 :integer         not null, primary key
...
#  user_id            :integer
#  term_type          :string(255)`
```

term.rb:

```
  class Term < ActiveRecord::Base 
validates   :term_type,         :inclusion => { :in => %w(Term Segment Entity Abbreviation) }`
```

Rails 3.0.3, ruby 1.8.7, Windows via Cygwin
The validation does not seem to work, i.e. it accepts any value for term_type.
When using inclusion (or validates_inclusion_of which produces the same fail condition) do I need DB validations matching those in the model?
Any issues with Strings I should be wary of?

Term_type is just a string in the DB and not a separate table.

Any pointers much appreciated.

Vince

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried using

```
validates :field, :inclusion => %{abc ade aeee}
```